# Retrieving a range of data from values Berkeley DB

Tags: python, database, berkeley-db, bsddb

How can I retrieve a range of data such as 10 < value < 20 from Berkeley DB? I use Python with bsddb3.

Comment: which version of python and bsddb are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pack integer with `struct.pack` or rely on something like [lexode](https://github.com/amirouche/python-lexode)